# C# Selenium: Click button under iframe

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have a iframe modal under my site. I am trying to click button in
    it but I am unable to do so. Below is my code. Please let me know
    what am i missing

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframeid='frame_name'"))); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("sendReuqest")).Click();
```

**Expected Result:** Button id: sendRequest should get clicked which is on iframe

**Actual Result:** Element is not found.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please next time considering to ask unrelated questions separately.

Comment: Where is unrelated question here?

Comment: I mean 2 different questions: 1) click button inside frame 2) check total time to load a grid, does it answer your question? Thanks!

Comment: Both are related to one thing which is Selenium Automation which I added as title of my question as well. I will remove one question. And will ask that in my seperate post. Thanks!!

Comment: Coolawesome, also please explain `unable to do so`. Do you have any exceptions? If yes, please include it in the question.

Comment: I updated my description.

Comment: It's getting better ;-) You know that it's always better to put whole exception from stacktrace. Last thing: we need html snippet with your iframe or (if possible) link to web page.

Comment: It would be useful to post the HTML of the `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it this way. Let's take frame_name id as iframe_1. Whatever you frame id is you can add instead of iframe_1. Also you have a spelling mistake (typo) it might be sendRequest so I am adding as id of your button.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement("iframe_1"))); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("sendRequest")).Click();
```

Hope it works. Please do comment and let us know.

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, now  I am able to click that button but I am facing another problem. Steps is to open that frame,click on button, frame closes,then it clicks on another button. When button is clicked on that frame and then frame gets closed but now not able to click on next button

Comment: I am receving this error: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `By.Id()` when you should be using `By.CssSelector()`.  `By.Id()` expects you to pass a parameter which matches the ID element in the HTML.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[iframeid='frame_name']"))); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("sendReuqest")).Click();
```

Comment: `sendReuqest` also doesn't look like a valid id.

Answer (score 0):

Try that one:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame_name"); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("sendReuqest")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks Leon. But Answer posted by user3542501 worked so I am going to use that. Appreciate your help.