# C# Selenium: Not able to get back to initail page

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, automation

In regards to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422364/c-sharp-selenium-click-button-under-iframe) I am unable to get back to initial page after Iframe modal closes.

I tries using

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
string currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle; //called before iframe modal popup window is called to open.
driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
```

But Failed to do so and receives error:   ----> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up.

**Expected Result:** button should get clicked

**Actual Result:** Receives an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved

```
string currentWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle; 
driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("@XpathLocation")).Click();
```

It was not recognising Id and even class so I add `Xpath with calling curent window handler` and it worked.